# Newtonsoft C# Convert JSON with different types in one array to Entity

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to convert/map a JSON result that can have a selection of different types in its properties;

For example:

```
"randomProperties": [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": 22
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "value": "somestring"
    },  
    {
        "name": "foobar",
        "value": {
          "type": "sometype",
          "currency": "EUR",
          "amount": 20,
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "entity",
        "value": {
          "typeId": "key-value-document",
          "id": "36cxx0f3-6b76-4d7b-8ea7-577fe44ab308"
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to convert this to this model:

```
public class RandomProperties
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]        
    public ValueObject ValueObject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]        
    public int? ValueInt { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("value")]        
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
}

public class ValueObject
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public int? Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("typeId")]
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ValueId { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use the JsonConverter, but i could only manage to keep one of the types. How would I map a random result like this?

Comment: Have a single `value` property of type `JToken`?

Answer (score 0):

try this, and you will have to fix classes too

```
    var randomPropertiesParsed = JObject.Parse(json); 

    var rp = new RandomProperties();
    foreach (JObject item in (JArray)randomPropertiesParsed["randomProperties"])
    {
        switch (item["value"].Type.ToString())
        {
            case "String":
                rp.ValueString = item.ToObject<ValueString>();
                break;

            case "Integer":
                rp.ValueInt = item.ToObject<ValueInt>();
                break;

            case "Object":
                if (item["value"]["type"] != null)
                    rp.ValueObjectType = item.ToObject<ValueObject>();
                else
                    rp.ValueObjectTypeId = item.ToObject<ValueObject>();
                break;
        }
    }
```

classes

```
public class RandomProperties
{

    public ValueObject ValueObjectType { get; set; }

    public ValueObject ValueObjectTypeId { get; set; }

    public ValueInt ValueInt { get; set; }

    public ValueString ValueString { get; set; }
}
public class ValueInt
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int value { get; set; }
}
public class ValueString
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class ValueObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public ValueOfObject value { get; set; }

}
public class ValueOfObject
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public int? Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("typeId")]
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ValueId { get; set; }
}
```